# Calculating euclidean distance between consecutive points of an array with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

I have an array which describes a polyline (ordered list of connected straight segments) as follows:

```
points = ((0,0),
          (1,2),
          (3,4),
          (6,5),
          (10,3),
          (15,4))
points = numpy.array(points, dtype=float)
```

Currently, I get a list of segment distances using the following loop:

```
segdists = []
for seg in xrange(points.shape[0]-1):
    seg = numpy.diff(points[seg:seg+2], axis=0)
    segdists.append(numpy.linalg.norm(seg))
```

I would like, instead, to apply a single function call, without loops, using some native Scipy/Numpy function.

The closest thing I could get is this:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
segdists = pdist(points, metric='euclidean')
```

but in this later case, segdists provides EVERY distance, and I want to get only the distances between adjacent rows.

Also, I'd rather avoid creating custom functions (since I already have a working solution), but instead to use more "numpythonic" use of native functions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's one way:

Use the vectorized [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) to compute the deltas:

```
d = np.diff(points, axis=0)
```

Then use [`np.hypot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hypot.html) to compute the lengths:

```
segdists = np.hypot(d[:,0], d[:,1])
```

Or use a more explicit computation:

```
segdists = np.sqrt((d ** 2).sum(axis=1))
```

Comment: After some dead-ends by myself, when you put it that way it's actually very straightforward. I've seen `hypot` being mentioned before, but googling "numpy hypot" doesn't return anything, I had to search at the numpy docs page. Thanks!

Comment: Is this also possible in 3D ?

Comment: @Varlor: Not with `hypot`, but the second version, `segdists = np.sqrt((d ** 2).sum(axis=1))`, works in 3D.